# why intensity become 4 times in constructive interference?

Tags: interference

why intensity become 4 times in constructive interference? I know the I is proportional to $A^2$ .  So when two waves with same phase, frequency and amplitude(A)superimpose, we get a wave with amplitude 2A is obtained. So, its intensity becomes 4 times. I want to know from where did that extra intensity/energy come from. (Since more intensity means nore energy.)

PS: 1) f you say it comes from destructive part then I would tell that during experiment in interferometer on    https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg  ,it returned back to source.

2) If above experiment does not matter and example of YDSE is given, then what if we consider only two waves with no wave to show destructive interference?

Comment: What "extra energy"?

Comment: You'd be wrong then, since "returned back to source" has no meaning.

Comment: please refer link that I give in question and explain why it is not considered here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'extra energy' DOES come from the destructive part, and the interferometer argument has nothing to do with it, because you get the same effect in Young's double-slit experiment (where no light returns to the source).

It's conservation of energy at its finest.

EDIT:
You seem intent to keep the interferometer in the argument, so let me be clear: the interferometer is a red-hearing you are clinging to. SURE, in an interferometer, some of the lighe goes back to the source, but it ALSO comes back with an interference pattern, in which there's regions of complete darkness, and regions of twice the light (4 times the intensity).

Bottom line: the interferometer doesn't matter, and does not prove anything. Do a simple double-slit experiment. NO light is coming back to the source, and still you get an interference pattern. Still some regions are dark, and some have twice the light. Still energy conservation.

Sorry if I seem a bit harsh, but you need to let the interferometer go =]

Comment: Please refer new Link I had added.

Comment: Please refer to my edit.

Comment: I finally understood it today.

Answer (score 2):

The factors 2 for amplitude, and 4 for intensity are a special case, where you have two waves interfering with similar amplitude

$$A_1=sin(k_1x), A_2=sin(k_2x)$$,

when $k_1x = k_2x = \pi/2 + N\pi$, where N is integer, both sines have a value of +1 or -1. At this particular point we have $A_{tot}=A_1+A_2=2A_1$, and $I=A_{tot}^2=(A_1+A_2)^2=A_1^2+A_2^2+2A_1A_2 = 4A_1^2$.

But in general you were concerned about where the power/energy comes from. It doesn't come out of nowhere, but it actually is conserved. Think of a general case of superposition of interfering waves

$$A(r)=\sum_k c_k exp(ikr)$$,

here k is the wave vector of particular wave in a box of length L ($k=n 2\pi/L$), and $c_k$ is the linear expansion coefficient of that wave. It is easy to construct coefficients $c_k$, which will make the maximum intensity 100 times larger. Now, look at the resulting total energy

$$E_{tot} = \int_0^L dr I(r)= \int_0^L dr  |A(r)|^2=\int_0^L dr  |\sum_k c_k exp(ikr)|^2$$

We can further write the sum open

$$ E_{tot} = \sum_{k'k} c_k c^*_{k'} \int_0^L dr exp(i(k-k')r))$$.

We find that the plane waves are orthogonal

$$\int dr exp(i(n 2\pi /L - n' 2\pi /L)r)) = L \delta_{nn'}$$, and we end up in a following expression for the total energy

$$ E_{tot} = \sum_{k} |c_k|^2 L $$.

Indeed, we find that the total energy is a sum of wave energies at particular wave vector. Thus interference only affects the spatial distribution of intensity, not the total energy transmitted by waves. I was talking about total energy here, since I was not conserning myself with time dependence of the waves, but the phenomenom is identical, and can be attributed to properties of fourier transform.

To further scrutinize, what happends to he intensity/energy, we can take a look of a cross-terms $k \neq k'$ in the intensity expansion

$$ c_k c_{k'}^* exp(i(k-k')x) + c.c. $$

This will be a oscillating wave at 0..L, but will always integrate to zero. It will always be real, since interchanging k and k' one has the complex conjugate. Here you see explicitly the effect of the interference to intensity. It shifts the intensity from one place to another, conserving energy.

Comment: This is a very detailed answer, but it might overwhelm the casual reader :-)